# Why doesn't my code work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (-10,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (0,5*sqrt(2*sqrt(2)-2));
        \coordinate (D) at (-5-5*sqrt(2),5*sqrt(2*sqrt(2)-2));
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: true, but dosent seem to be the problem

Comment: You need to enclose the calculations within `{`...`}` to avoid the parser getting confused with the parentheses: `\coordinate (C) at (0,{5*sqrt(2*sqrt(2)-2)});`

Answer (score 1):

[As Werner pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530295/why-doesnt-my-code-work#comment1340996_530295), you need only to add braces. I am writing this because I do not think it is a good idea to mix `fpeval`. Unless you are very careful in what you are doing. Of course, if you are super careful and know what Ti*k*Z does internally, you can use it, and then it is a great tool. But there is absolutely no need for that here, nor for loading the `calc` library. And no, parsing expressions in coordinates is not a pain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (-10,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (0,{5*sqrt(2*sqrt(2)-2)});
        \coordinate (D) at ({-5-5*sqrt(2)},{5*sqrt(2*sqrt(2)-2)});
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I will be happy to remove this if Werner writes an answer.

Here is a why I do not recommend to mix in `fpeval`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (\fpeval{3pt+2cm},1);
\draw[blue] (0,0) -- ({3pt+2cm},1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Again, if you understand the internals of Ti*k*Z well enough, you will be fine, but I do not think it is a great recommendation for general users to mix in `\fpeval` without a clear warning.

Comment: The given document doesn't use explicit units. Is there *any* reason to?

Comment: @egreg Yes, there are many cases in which units are useful. And they are used in many cases without the user knowing it, e.g. in `tikz-3dplot`. As I wrote, if you fully understand what happens behind the scenes, `\fpeval` is a great tool, but I would not want to blindly recommend to mix it into `tikzpicture`s, especially if the user is struggling with rather basic problems.

Comment: How can adding `3pt` to `2cm` be possible? I mean, they have different measurement units.

Comment: @manooooh `tikz` converts internally everything to `pt` so it is possible. Even `xfp` does, `\fpeval{3pt+2cm}` yields `59.90551181102362`, which is 2 times `28.45275590551181` (1cm=28.45275590551181pt) plus 3. The trouble is that `\fpeval` strips the units. And this is what can cause problems, as illustrated in the simple example.